# Alphabet Aerobics

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

## Challenge

Given a single letter (a-z) as input, output the 2 lines of Blackalicious' *[Alphabet Aerobics](https://youtu.be/MvPnM2Q1nwU)* that correspond to that letter (ignoring the intro & outro).

---

### Rules

- You may take input by any reasonable, convenient means as long as it's permitted by [standard I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/58974).
- Input must either be case insensitive or consistently uppercase or lowercase.
- Output may be a newline separated string or an array/list of two strings.
- Output must be formatted (capitalisation, punctuation, etc.) exactly as it appears in the test cases below.
- Trailing spaces and newlines are not allowed.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so lowest byte count wins.

---

### Test Cases

Each code block below is what should be output for each letter a-z, respectively.

```
Artificial amateurs, aren't at all amazing
Analytically, I assault, animate things
```

```
Broken barriers bounded by the bomb beat
Buildings are broken, basically I'm bombarding
```

```
Casually create catastrophes, casualties
Canceling cats got they canopies collapsing
```

```
Detonate a dime of dank daily doin' dough
Demonstrations, Don Dada on the down low
```

```
Eating other editors with each and every energetic
Epileptic episode, elevated etiquette
```

```
Furious, fat, fabulous, fantastic
Flurries of funk felt feeding the fanatics
```

```
Gift got great, global goods gone glorious
Gettin' godly in his game with the goriest
```

```
Hit em high, hella height, historical
Hey holocaust hints, hear 'em holler at your homeboy
```

```
Imitators idolize, I intimidate
In a' instant, I'll rise in a' irate state
```

```
Juiced on my jams like Jheri curls jockin' joints
Justly, it's just me, writing my journals
```

```
Kindly I'm kindling all kinds of ink on
Karate kick type Brits in my kingdom
```

```
Let me live a long life, lyrically lessons is learned
Lame louses just lose to my livery
```

```
My mind makes marvelous moves, masses
Marvel and move, many mock what I've mastered
```

```
Niggas nap knowing I'm nice, naturally
Knack, never lack, make noise nationally
```

```
Operation, opposition, off not optional
Out of sight, out of mind, wide beaming opticals
```

```
Perfected poem, powerful punchlines
Pummeling Petty powder puffs in my prime
```

```
Quite quaint quotes keep quiet it's Quannum
Quarrelers ain't got a quarter of what we got, uh
```

```
Really raw raps, risin up rapidly
Riding the rushing radioactivity
```

```
Super scientifical sound search sought
Silencing super fire saps that are soft
```

```
Tales ten times talented, too tough
Take that, challengers, get a tune up
```

```
Universal, unique, untouched
Unadulterated, the raw uncut
```

```
Verb vice lord victorious valid
Violate vibes that are vain, make em vanish
```

```
Why I'm all well, what a wise wordsmith just
Weaving up words, weeded up on my workshift
```

```
Xerox, my X-radiation holes extra large
X-height letters and xylophone tones
```

```
Yellow-back, yak mouth, young ones' yaws
Yesterday's lawn yardsale, I yawned
```

```
Zig-Zag zombies, zooming to the zenith
Zero in, zen thoughts, overzealous rhyme ZEA-LOTS!
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the challenge doesn't seem very interesting because the text lacks structure to allow clever compression tricks

Comment: @LuisMendo, you'd imagine someone would have seen fit to mention that in the *week* this was sitting in the Sandbox, wouldn't you? But, no, all it got there were 4 upvotes and a few comments, none of which provided any constructive feedback. Which makes me question the point of having a Sandbox at all!

Comment: I agree, downvotes without comments are not very useful, specially in the sandbox

Comment: @Shaggy A lot of ppl question sandbox, just see posts about it in Meta

Comment: @Shaggy The sandbox is just a place where you can draft your challenges. In order to get suggestions and feedback you actively have to ask people about the things you're not sure about.

Comment: @flawr, search TNB for "[Alphabet Aerobics](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=alphabet+aerobics&room=240)" ;) - and they're just the ones I "oneboxed".

Comment: More downvotes without a single one of them having the courtesy to provide a single line of feedback! :( Much more and I'll have to delete this - it's the hour and a half that Erik spent on his solution that's staying my hand from doing so now.

Comment: @Shaggy sorry but it's here forever now. You can't delete posts with upvoted answers

Comment: I downvoted because of Luis Mendo's reason. The challenge seems uninteresting as there is not much interesting compression techniques in the text.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, @KritixiLithos; just a shame nobody thought to mention it while this was still in Sandbox.

Comment: Whoever takes the time to answer this in 05AB1E wins... Just saying, it won't even be fair.

Comment: Nevermind, half of those words are slang; 05AB1E would get wrecked.

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 1678 bytes

```php
<?=ucfirst($argn),strtr(explode(_,gzinflate(base64_decode("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")))[ord($argn)%32-1],[in,at,er,al,es,th,ou,on,ic,ar]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LZXHyuSIAYTv8xiDDfOjXlo5MB4vymrFVg7LMijnLLWkPvit9zz72/j8VUEdqqipmn796/epmr7kyzIuP5d8GpetHspv/@F/6obzYPmP71/@ES/l8ONr@vX7l9///an/sadFvazbt/@Bj9u6LdvyLT@nbszybz9v5bseii7e8m9JvOY4@jPL0/@Sr6oXyO12wJyKLArGOAEyz9vTgzdRG8hIuSRnl1F0V/halIU2UALd8QsJzPVACzmzZn0GzUEWH@/zOPPDkwGLtkGyMqUrz43zhg/fWKuCF1T5e7ddBvXIRarmxtS2akFGHIWhSNQgxIraIxePW0okexseIcNR4MyHZ@wSMHGyvRWN7jFSYI@l4GQ1AbG3@qo4M9ZJTpqMtTiQKmAZOA9WB7M7GGfnRS@qvAuxQ9@fJgg/aGKtElGd5/7tjy/hOEWJfR@Ptp/6tYHk0I5IQT7V/qQew5ieORm8GYtXMlealosA7bZiOszGNinj4A1P6ElaZ9v2la4Z8BgzTuWRlCHdBuuuw7LJVfALzjsx7hC6CyYbacc7328pG0qM@bwU6eAhEB9Pswj5O@jGlISa8vw04nscN@lVsnARWnARr/Qb1QJBVlZ231@dQMHamtO6aDE9krB9utBpLIDvXrgkTDIEE/MfPZueo7eUvmkbAwcd7GI05sxrACppYdOY75HUXOaeulwn7dvaADTR1xDhOmCZhiQgWvgI6jirWmoruoRBlu8NiZao8pVKNmxv3iRnduQSmz2Vq4jw06U8U0bIn/XIuRhmDZgZgymwexwdsfthnCwJJsWZn/KMDhPhlTM@q86wEEnSyhNyQdeVofUMWrpg4qhtD0YtdYhSsiBmSKtj@EnAoU4SKrxI0UnbUiZ26tk6pAgjAzuPelsYzDJ2YhFawC5HqUbIPMnHpEGuOxXMWFLo3uiE5fhbApTRZ7N0UrtyDCit4blMmA1akcTIA3W4PqFbg7bHVuQ4hb5FXmMnQn4UWkxDWV/YSepwwmT4oxYo8msPUf5qaVczyf5yU618Mv0Jis4qRX73WEGvAQ9LClQVqQbLcWp2xi2ED8So4ZGHCNGFtUK22dR2YCWLlzXCa8z0kl4k5bWa5qGqT0JqXgxl0jjj8/VTD1vsTb9CjlDVQZ1ZoQYCrDYAilCMXo6mHZL6rAjf7xd9PyyEAe17fp0iUjxBAzAe58pDXglUgiC9WGiMYzkPxRF8zBQcAbXGJgYcZ2iKX2fuWkAujxqd6IkiGAobU8TY7HbTP7nZ6wzkKSKllpYBiJ22nQplb93nPLNSSny28mVe47jPgi8sYafaCeYkumosWtWAkTSIUMycFyrDfq69gOF4s4UaNIMp@tLoKfaGwWDRf460FPzPfIx5WBp3@PRWJbb@mm1g4DgX8RoG8uja8g8fYow6tJ1YVDnJuxphevj2fczeOiofxblWa1Soj6bTmJgRUQbiXCIGg1YQ8cvmV5GU/HrtVgRwIZ@j5m3BjTTzMO2@HhL78p8CkGjxsKcSjah82TR7TXeglOfEgfvp2vHORQikr6CjNKhr3m1VGtK8C1wnZ9xbC8bXiUipBhxOyqZZLhd7C9LMe0nqB2ImxqtBScKWNPeopy3kcAxPThulPeHCoBJy1nssZXhyyXWevNlUjTjJnjiKS4siKiR3nPSGEVjgfRF2RG0x2SDyRKUVDtQhn5Pp3mhS/4TqUAnBkUEuLcnSGeiikGZpDLQrSHSCcJOIli17ItUMtQgWCs2f9@oCsuJepj@@fnx8/DEu2f9P5Z8I/Bv05@2PerjF2y1fbnF3y9fbVt3G/TYOtzq9xcufH99//fprGH9L47TK/wY)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 1952 bytes

```php
<?=ucfirst($argn),explode(_,strtr("rtif8i3 am1eurs, 9en't 1 3l amaz0g
An3yt83ly, I assault, anim1e 50gs_roken b9ri2s b6nded by 5e bomb be1
Build0gs 9e broken, bas83ly I'm bomb9d0g_asu3ly cre1e c1astroph4, casu3ti4
Cancel0g c1s got 5ey canopi4 collaps0g_et71e a dime of dank daily do0' d6gh
Dem7str1i7s, D7 Dada 7 5e down low_10g o52 editors wi5 each and ev2y en2get8
Epilept8 episode, elev1ed etiquette_uri6s, f1, fabul6s, fantast8
Flurri4 of funk felt feed0g 5e fan18s_ift got gre1, glob3 goods g7e glori6s
Gett0' godly 0 his game wi5 5e gori4t_it em high, hella height, histor83
Hey holocaust h0ts, he9 'em holl2 1 y6r homeboy_mit1ors idolize, I 0timid1e
In a' 0stant, I'll rise 0 a' ir1e st1e_u8ed 7 my jams like Jh2i curls jock0' jo0ts
Justly, it's just me, writ0g my j6rn3s_0dly I'm k0dl0g 3l k0ds of 0k 7
K91e k8k type Brits 0 my k0gdom_et me live a l7g life, lyr83ly l4s7s is le9ned
Lame l6s4 just lose to my liv2y_y m0d mak4 m9vel6s mov4, mass4
M9vel and move, many mock wh1 I've mast2ed_iggas nap know0g I'm n8e, n1ur3ly
Knack, nev2 lack, make noise n1i73ly_p21i7, oppositi7, off not opti73
Out of sight, 6t of m0d, wide beam0g opt83s_2fected poem, pow2ful punchl04
Pummel0g Petty powd2 puffs 0 my prime_uite qua0t quot4 keep quiet it's Quannum
Qu9rel2s a0't got a qu9t2 of wh1 we got, uh_e3ly raw raps, ris0 up rapidly
Rid0g 5e rush0g radioactivity_up2 scientif83 s6nd se9ch s6ght
Silenc0g sup2 fire saps 51 9e soft_34 ten tim4 t3ented, too t6gh
Take 51, ch3leng2s, get a tune up_niv2s3, unique, unt6ched
Unadult21ed, 5e raw uncut_2b v8e lord v8tori6s v3id
Viol1e vib4 51 9e va0, make em vanish_hy I'm 3l well, wh1 a wise wordsmi5 just
Weav0g up words, weeded up 7 my workshift_2ox, my X-radi1i7 hol4 extra l9ge
X-height lett2s and xyloph7e t74_ellow-back, yak m65, y6ng 74' yaws
Y4t2day's lawn y9ds3e, I yawned_ig-Zag zombi4, zoom0g to 5e zeni5
Z2o 0, zen 56ghts, ov2ze36s rhyme ZEA-LOTS!",[in,at,er,al,es,th,ou,on,ic,ar]))[ord($argn)%32-1];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LVXbbtw2EH3XV0yNFmsDMqDb3pCmQS5u6yRtkiZt0wSBwJVGEi2KVEhq1/JD/7rP6aHsh@UOh8O5HJ4Zjd347ccnYzdGbK2xpeXRWC91e/7vVfn7mw/Xz68uHkXfC9vqx2d3Z4@iJz/B/vFUNdI6f74cXMR8OypT83kZO2@9PT@Di2YncxJDypN1Me1ZrzyllCvoxF3SRk91PvtdruaYrkk4JyblYxJa4gqtk9aV1vSs6bC3MnN02OiaazrMtGY6mOFAB06jZ5NUNWzhnw6LfUwH4YJbul4Ni@EeBqVwU9BVluG9SgXyNGNXxFSFEy@L6LnQFaukxamj1njEgb3QZpQFVUYpMTo4Yr@FB0G1HJhMQ7XQPRYJ57VJVlRv2i56wcMWEVK5RekvtvRC1IK2IfPanDQpcypTRDLrjLiW3lhHJ7kmFlUHBGriYzYT66xlv4uuRql49DviUTqgHBMrPqYAg738OrH3XE5WbhCqSfETh0ktG6E96txFP6vJWhSBbJsJ2TasPBYGLiEl2KU7V8rGL2W3gCimVplDjr2pAcaWwz6EiH5BOFTZmhoFJ9RJHAsgEdKHrxZWhS@lJx5w2HYxdQzosGKD98UFlLvLo1@BbmeUqcTkPHWJd8F0T6twEWhnIMu8sZAHPpi5HKRPA06yNkrecSBN4uUg65Sja01iRYnzqBgHK6XISsfID2pp8V7OpwBpB8y2NMx0IwZHSvZML7tMUjVZ5ejGVD1KuzHIJXqJrAI1pV/hJKQ4IObJSg/QgoeN1bkrk/qBaD0knIDekFyAOulpG73aI3i/68nPI9MzXHfICvf7pK3NADbBLzI5BkqpbQuxQRw124XCqnBblIxcea@5jl4HqPG4xX1KyqBIb4I/uMjmcqYhqWkQfUHD/siwpMEcwfIBDVZEvwXdQjBoOWg1bqBsOnUpykAWMPQZ16VsW@FIi5F6bU6oLBSpd7ik08kit@iVFlWPLbhKahERl0mbgLwG9WFUjhmEmMw4Gif9IjYNbDxU2ObRm8kHsNw9OzbLBjUAalmjpVkMoU/AfoCdNVx5POFoeIixnrJmUjROuupUUkRvp2FYGvgtODqH8zrDadM8QD5atGw5Sc/0dRKJx2p8QT3zCFHiKZbHfjcJrachejftLStMHpGs7jtDwGzvs5BiwOsU6I6kp67k8FhWnPAbwWOQL6FpDDsJgkR/yIdWs5PrIFlRSyMqL4/Sz@U0ZuQqyTrMzJwcBh053mMUOMwSH71H@@sK11ywxNwFnRGG1mmYes40vswL8hiV6AcIOTwxEPTGkA/T6EN4lzWauupyuGozpIjJgnr8pBmJlhrscTlK0WGghH@/qToQ7k8taszlLA0OQwGoEXhPvswOdNyBjMbWEPwyHeiYyzr6SxoF1h/loXjI8SiSB3aguY8Y8a4ru/u@QcOcMCDiBVGBVwd5TvDpBgyUQPLobxZHFA84Fz0sMbnAAiiWXoa2dx2mV5mZ2zhoPl4GgEG8MEgK4ltv0Vz7lqOPl/dzCP3kfXhaQH07K3wJMOL8tiiRijldHhY6z6KnYbOGsNEtbYsVNCcX/VP4rBYzmKIEZvm8r12@jCOc6qVzLj@Jlu7w5ZHovDtjAoXRpYDvjrVcR58yQwAEG1qHF0ZN5pjdcQ4EbTejxT9dPb18/ebD@@/O4s9Sx8LHbGOhYnax72IzxUbHsoqF/XJx8RmoPHyHf8izy/TLo2/f/tPmssLHhP8H)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>1052</s> 1050 bytes

```
Oị“>ḤĖwỌḞaỌHtṂþÐṿɼ×ƙ\ṀẸqė\ȧIɓịżʂñ"ḃ⁺ụPE4ĿɲɗŀÐ“¡Ƭ£`BrjŒ⁷ḷḊwṡxṙṀrẇp[ṣİ|ḲṬ⁹ⱮØẎ9ṙ“¡Npḥ8Þṿfeṗẋ⁶ż⁹ẎUøịẹYḄnṁ7ZMnb~pOṙɗḣ(Œøṙụ;ḥ⁸ƇṚỊsẎʋðỴİc⁽Ċ“jɲḷȦẒḲƑzRṀ7¥(æċȧƭḶZṘḄƤ`¬?^ḞƙṾƲq“S£÷ƑØQQʠaƭỴȤ_TỴkɦṛ¥gṄĿ²ṆḍḣṾ2ɓṘ ,“¡ẏŒpḌBḢ/c{ḶẒẠf%nM⁼ṃṫQʂrɱṿ¬4ɱUƘMẸṛŻƬÑ“¡Ɱ1ṣḞµ⁶ỌrTXçYṗ$Ȥẋ-ocñƲ“Ñ³{gøUƤ5]ẈṂȮɦµṂTœỌŒ1/Ẇ~œy2¦æƲȧ€ƝGb“€ẉ⁹6¬ƁṡLæẏẏẹyƈ"ð~¢5_Ɲḣ⁸¶mẇn⁷S9EṃẈM'}0ⱮƁṘṢŀ"¬U#~+ẋV“.¹ṗẸ6æAWḣ⁺tɼZĿẓṃẎ⁽C#ẇṣṡẆX½⁵ỵ€⁼µþȦ/]ȥṪ1“~Ṇẇ{KH9kẉḊẠ¢ỊẇLṖṛPḤ£\tkŻbḍṀPJ¡ȧṚ~QNNØ}ȷṬ“¢jÇṘ4ḥs"⁼ụ¦ṣƭRḤḍḄ$Ẉ9⁷JÞ,ẹƓ3ṡọRƓṃØ×ẠȮḞẹ+hṫ}5[ĿpQƇ(“-G>ɦɼ⁽⁷ĿtḌŒƤifLƥƒẠḄḊɲɲðṭŀRṚ-*ƭṭyƝ(Ṙḣ“¡o|ỤṛỊ iżẈṄʂtÞ⁵x⁵ⱮṫE⁾Ḋ`ıĖẹjp½ḳ{HlọḣoẎ“-ḃ]"ṅỊȮmJỵṖ<)ỴƝD_wȤ⁺ḣ4Mœnu⁴jḅȦ5“©ẆẸṡA*ßx⁹ƤƝO¹ṣUṡ4ė-ƲȤ⁾ḃKhTẸ⁵ḅ-⁻nẊẈ"nwỴß⁼ ɗ“ṡṖḟYIɱẉcẓ⁻tŻƊẎ- ṡİȮgṅƝ×`®*çq¡þ⁹Xe“µÑe0Ƭ¦w$ƊIḶ1\"Ɗø,7v&€/$jṠƝȧḋẓœẆĠc“¢ȷCṁ$°ṬḅṿkėḣC{AịB£AtṅẊRWGḂ2µ9ḌUḣœ⁵mⱮṛ⁷ṙḄḟkẆ¦œ“ƭÆ|ƤBċȦlĊæʠȥiƒ.nżṘḃọṬµṛHⱮW^ṗɲḄbX{ḊṾ3ḃʂ5⁸Ẇẓ)ẹ“¦+8ɼġtịḂZṄ⁽ƙḍṄØM.ƙḞȥU$İ¶r¡ṅ¦3Ṗ£|ƘẎẋḌF÷ẋ⁵“⁹ƓBrḍṆdmṫ©ⱮĠ£ƬƘḟ}ėm9ʂaȧQ÷ɲṭẒḃĿƒỊ,ṛ0¬¿Ɠẉṛr!rƑWĠƭ¢/,⁼ẋ'o“@⁶⁵*ƊÇṡḳƈ/ƒĿĠỌ59KɼẸṅ¦⁶Ġƙ'ƒjḶV¡Pḃ÷Ḷıʋʋḣ³8Ẇs“ȷṪjLZ÷\ĠṫĊɼƒiB½mṾf÷²ṭ³¦ṇḷµœ¢żA¢,Mḷȷ¢æⱮBḥṿḥ£İ“¡EȷịḢ/"µİ3ȧÆỴʂJ]Uƈ{Ṙ]¿þLÞƇe/ẏ⁸ƒ÷œTḃṠyuṫḍ0ɠẸ“¢ṂṖ^YḳN:⁵ẓ⁴⁸ịṚ(NṫCṭḂḷcʂW¦ṅƇẓḷ¥b⁵QSYŀ⁽×»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HVUJUxNJGP0rLLIrIggoqOxuuQssKyKgIMghKMKCciPiIstRJJwGL5IqEg8g5JiUGiiukOlJIFXdM10z@RedP8K@nqpAUkn3973vvfe9GegdGpo6P78nEmuZ@a@3hBrSNyZF4q1Qt57irXpCECc7Yx8FSVlJ5uWfOgSZF5r6Qvd2mJE7lgcXjWTayQ6yhbqQcWgiEb5fVaKnrEPLa8yzj6hKd3iUBrsqxgcMd8YRFyperklBdl4L8gnlxoW2MvZIkKC@PyPUQ0GiGQfJHOwxn9Del@GMXaN@TKjhm2wLSPp6BfEKbS3jODGSOItjzUwFEqGRNqEujgjiuNFeN9I9N3YP1y2vUIO5hhtH0C8R/g2FMg6VrwjyWSRcL3E9vcb2ReJY3@/JOE51FxoOWIcAaipCcwMTX/@vEUhv0HAuU/Q1M8J3hXrSLogP7Xioi0b/eAzKOMY544cvcP8BDbI4X2e@hoa0/ymOJ47N0JMmvA1aiiBfaPiZIIt6imLeZaG@A0TcvQpCiS8r355YaB8MN6Z@WyHUQGHPNDpKNJq/7@eRuowjKciCID8a0s5x6wCs0GiJddDMfXWQBw2MBI@ydbsQuCwGvQBIY@AMuo43tbJIG1jMMUMgsmC0hx3wQxxm6/Ro@hlTm3motFNoq5Df3LMUGsOHJgNqvzXcxYVCW54zPFNXqcIUfmhGMs4o37zdjfv4JLQ30OQ6jXIHNK5loPCD/SJTfDWb7c/RQOkTvomBIQI9GYb6I7DFg7IqOZC2WndxtgiI5W2fIAFjPptGmy/MXQbOh@hwhRJbffU6U8pb7CrahJVs11NC89gV3kPDygsoK2cmoHG5lZ5mHDGRiAEeiKMxdmYqhZ1mWJDvxag5JzXQVqbvVpcNAj7sCZZpAObAt7WCbIDP@9gNGuyYGDQS3VIvMn@/hu6YEZhorqG@nvlmzbi0LggPDDD09pXAZy@zpVCJMIXmQb7biCK22Is5mLQMY9ewrXxQwz3XJNTEu0Yuh2A@hhH95h40w6@Xn0Po2dJHemqsga/kokfB7VuWYsH8GCyupybgEsPNQ/19tTzMpUfQAmNgCw/hbLJrzMO/nwvyYESyO8U3c23rBm17jM6IRAgTYtysfiNpq76Ydk6wLZD2Gn9QA/2rMo4zlOzSD/QNYBoYo6dCPZquHgJqlBqVxAMYYqAzW5AlVDP3hmtAOvj7/RKMzzf/ejJphmRIqMGSOsMz8irjOB4Q6pKplEok3yCVbd6d8jy2jc6Eh/jmPSl4sBnflujeAtgtZANZuPu8CYelrupSQcaRGBEa5FrNHkF@HbNt8J5leVFW8goF1e22O9gT7U0PfILjE1gQnH9fkIUD@r65h31c4pvM20X38ljkBd1hZ0DQ2iuRxdh6bxFSTJnM4a47WMTijmzuYmr@jX9/gacKcwYE8fNNuEFFCHmwKNqy7u@xzWDGK5FHORQyRAEVmzqoy0SqnC5HZFXQYPmEpEtzNbbcFqrzKo2VQc1mnDCAMzZss/9FBifSS6q6DY8uUwW/zn/lu2x5hocqkEnKkO5iStpvhvu5@8oIhJQSL0h1SFQu8JdqlGp5jO2R2bbY3TotjU7OruFU2lmKbbT591yCuhK5cvmmldR3JmSwqk6E3SLshoiT5l9kvror8vOWGW7O0ffpyTgCiyxRBT7eoMEZLsMbK4tR/mZxO6xjMh@gqadi3K6x/M8wbEW/AZXup0EexR11e1b3DpelnU/NSAOLAyjZtSN4QU/B1wlXPuYoolGawp5gU8mX8Z/G@XqL7ue7NFCYL7dNW7s4ilZ/IurQNA86rUgPqEd8tZC79ZTuR4yVlt21krbZgBknUeDTRe6GG08e0h0s@wJQqyf6QXotjSGC9Ogm2HmJunLNvw/UtrN4ByqRH7rLSnJ3fwU9xThnfSwuI32XHsmVX8EzhMYMDw0YyXIayK@Tz5Q4DTAFQyPWEUAp/Kd49NmrWIXiku1AYTaN6fvXzAhbhpvTzprOZr46DUU7aYqd1bItvtKLGP4gn2NuFjc8TVJq4p96BURgt8jyy@WQ/kNyQ5LHeDAe1f8q10Xa/1iqjU7kc249blRKmlUn0PWknS0S@RIej8hTwA9341LDgzZjHvIzL02cn5@X/w8)

-2 thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan).

Accepts uppercase.

Ironic that <s>only the first three bytes do the real work</s> this program doesn't do any real work, isn't it?

*(tfw when it takes you more than an hour and a half but the result is perfect)*

Comment: An hour and a half?! :o I'm humbled that you would spend so much time on it :)

Comment: @Shaggy Most of it was generating the 1048 bytes at the end.

Comment: Save two bytes by only accepting lowercase and using `O`instead of `ØWw` - indexing into your list rotated left by 8.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Ooh great idea...but then I prefer uppercase so I'd rotate to the right by 12.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>2232</s> <s>2214</s> 2176 bytes

This is an anyonymous function with one huge string hardcoded. The different outputs are separated by a `)` which is then used in `strsplit`.

```matlab
@(n)strsplit("Artificial amateurs (...) overzealous rhyme ZEA-LOTS!",')'){n-96}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVXbbtxGDP0VNi@ygPVrgaIo0CTOxbk0SXM39DIrURKzI44yl93IRb/dPZx1iwK2di6cIXl4eCb02R357m787fcLbVOOafWSLx48jFlG6cV5covLXGLakYusTSaHP1/Xb0WnTh@q81uWHovbjq7JpeSKz7BXsbOUZ9il9lEMB1bauxiFY6J9KDrwQPsNFozpsqc9u9zpoyJ@sDPmkvb13A4H09kJXTdLNXfRrNrHLpW63kc2f73LDqmEdWZE3dfdLJw6fey0Z48zZpNoCtlc46DTsMKC@uC9W5PdesU5qF3naJCFKYw0OD3gI3A1BNEG3zLNnV7xEhQeXRb87ugqKF25wRF@LbUhnJR8OLVPYAHnAYuReJAcgMNJ8kzs@hmADcRHjhuxcpwYoHb6ZBXPK4bEq6Qw8I7Y8xGRwTjL98I5c/u0RAkFvkeX7bMv/n6qBoZd9NQXQz5ZJmNBJiP7jA8biDVOGCPAPrXPZMwVnckQ3dHkwx5UmEIYDDVlW6kOO30G/4bFFAbgIkqzwMYBsZqY3TsF85vb55KJFxhM845mBtT4YgIPOAQwrL6dPkdF5uBD70rK2NGczNxFauw0SgT0wMItlIjpwvuwtdeLZFfxlCF4uWWjIo7KIgOw6vRayTVYSRmQYLMBh6MktpBtI1qtsQkwXxTpgS6qt2z0zS2JvByYXqBqQn2JPtG30B8s62/Bwuv0BUI1@ktusGlxL4jgFKUW3K5BsGiU1L4UHe45fLCh7Vs/2aTWRlCaoJ2@dDWkg/QHytvK9Ai3JQsX18F6GsLSvmLzhPiORlQfcJmXEa79Fu@7xXNKoCWhLB4gKg@dvrL6GEP4PlofgEQOdrXdFbf29UYLQqLFHWC0uHhkO0BLOFpbLWhza6nXdaNS13ZsQ3ES8NBpRpGuG0QG48yRh/YPmSaXSN1KBw0ny92AUOC9w2ou0UJG7ur6A1asG8jXscVBGqxiWhvNLNs3K5/bbkdhXUOS@/E4wjZj7WzZ6ZuSDdx0pls4zyxBVEkGNuVZam@uVcpS@5bjyL112Rp42eF7wkrxtBbtZ5TNsn9bluUsKG/RBpsZDYh4LeP4b6XWCPVo3xVBLb8XB7rgJ2RgemBeMRaUsNLmXXGqZekUgxjR5CAz7JtzKzo7HQGjBV6hPVlnIZkyt39yLXV0J/yvKA@YDfdltakMBumf8l@fx5JMkrE3SHB9lqPkrX1fgCWlXlir@KPhk0k0JbAG6pRM7KDO76FH2tv5VE@MApFO8Iq77W2wWRhz@8GBeZQh@WhCG2GuwHMHngX8V@n8YFW1cxDqGTmwTmxvDcQPGecCqSlr@1GNk8l5JKsmefaLG/rZyPxR3YAHx4hQb7cMAQTKVHL7ieOejuAXKB4HG@WzctHRecHpTxK89dlR9vy/FI5A/p50EJ0j3rI0t5/nc@Nav56gX7tzIRwoBFqe4CAtJnrWUp1@Znc0mFCFugVriC0IhYWztmD5gFIArC8cw4@drX25tLJUTpvWISb@gacFXYAXodMvl2fJRC9D940hqNCPzeO1M13Gm8Wp/YrYwulyXxtncwf0Y8nQXCimUVy5weoJ/P3K1piD20A/7/BKbXhTgXNVT5hALNobmS5v3ES3eHHFWv82hNoqkAvD@pYVOXd6gxTIQLu1ks@VLbCGKMRb0NMgj/MG3bl58vDy1ZsP7396sGvapv1LL3/5@e9f7wZJ68V40fRN2979Aw)

Comment: Umm, the whole code actually fits in.

Comment: I got an error messages when I tried to include the code, feel free to try it yourself. (Actually I think it would not even be *that* interesting to see the rest of the code)

Comment: Then how is it 2176 bytes? Post limit is 30k chars.

Comment: Don't ask *me*, all I know is that I got an (unspecific) error message when I tried to submit that.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the TIO link's length? That's still not too long though... weird...

Comment: Yeah I thought that too first, but when I shortened it using tinyurl.com it said I was not allowed to use url shorteners...

Comment: @flawr I got a non-specific error message when submitting here too, but a couple page refreshes and attempts and an `I'm not a robot` verification it submitted.

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>1038</s> <s>992</s> 991 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
Ƨ, "&↑A○f8▓⁵√¹⅟²px∫Uw2ƧΚιx,═hνtεI   =*f⅞aG░‛I:┘'┘‽ΟΨ▲cμ⌠└ιŗY]š⅝&◄⅞▓æCæ»TUΓ↔τ┼≥{_‰ī(*#ģ↑ι<d^¹≈4┘¡ēY←z▓Β6→y⌠$<\ē⁵owD╬#οīλ3ņ┼┘Τ‰±╥μΛš^»KƧ↑³g(y.℮ēDī*█┘E>Ν,±→ø¶ΦKƨS⅝p□D>mƨYψCκΧū╥ō⌠d#╗ΞΡ⅝¬℮te%ΝH↑]ÆυΔ⅔;ΦVO⁹}≈Rōøυ#»→▒⁄w⌡σX╔⁾560yķψ┌λTHļķ:‛ļ:Ι≠sē8□v׀N‽MXσ&⁶┌■ qŗ3C‽Βσ4:Mk{∆▒ΨƧB ;uΡ│ΣV«ŗ╤f⌡E│?æ^νΠ‚H2ō6J>uΓηΣg.R╗|$R‼↑⅞▓^tlM║⁄bd9↔▒┐^Υ|πc⁷ø○āΟ‰□28O╤>V]lαÆøΡω┼|hΦWīūEξ5M¾(Y□ξ§+d¼r▒ģƧ╔ūl■ΡΝž@h∑κ⁸<K▼α≈βī‚⁰⁽N∙!⅟EΜ²█V¾>ΩΒEt═δ√qΛ≡w]ē↔Π⁾ΤXΒ7←η╬¶┌‰RVDΥζVΒ±%÷¤ν↔2Ζ'∙;σ¶▓m⁾ΧqΥ-Ƨυ)┐`θ∫%ψτ:←√′\Ay+‰≡≈ÆMāT┼5eτ^²─κGΘ⁷¾ayψJΘ׀G↓⅜!╔¡┌*«η[░≤k║ŗ«ΘθλΖ○Η▓|ūΕ╚↓ψƧ⅜λO¶μ⁽φ⁹╝╔Z⁽╥Σ←°e+)l$»≡≡m*≡ΞΤ‽|°eŗ)3²žΛ@crO1G└ZPvƧē√≡ΣGα.Σē╝Γ⌠ķa3J¹∞'√ā⅛νξwΤ³░ κē=mģσ↔║¶øø$!π+≡⁵⁴y▒'R≥Æķ+²⁸ēΖ⁄⅛↑↑A▲}<I‼⌠Ξ′╤Β¬C+■∫ο½⅞ΝL,#rΞ█↕ο∫8rL°νnc▼Γ)═^{Φ⅟ε³‛℮lƧčGP¾3◄Ω╗g2FAm׀λ$╗→rWΖ17⅜⌡◄Ič    εt≥q℮′?Æ>┐Τ'ņ¬V→⅔O¼■┼q,‼Β∆∆№ģW■°~¬l⁹ōJbbΘpRņžψ∞ζč╥⁵σθ≈≥⁸¤JÆε5]○¾f׀№ģ§:⅝æT¡⁷ΛΖΨ≤⅝χυ¼š:ÆΛ½±FυΚξū^ΧģƧ'↑KžΨ⁄²I;:χ~Ν(»%γp‽iξC⅝°§Ω≤lδ¦┼}℮≠lχ3╬L¦⁴Ο:gBš╔¶¤:ģMC%u÷⁴┘žYƧΣ0‛⁶0Δ.e_?[─9Νκ⅔⁷}ΦW#_↓δv≥╔Z⅞y4‽ūψqiΖW⁴ƨΡφ%7√‰η²¤š⁷╥⅞5┼/⅜ΔοΦR¾§l¶←∞‰σl1⅛!⁄⁴′νιvk⅓⁴⅛▓ε↑δ@╗ \η!└⅝S0┌²⁰≥¦⁵‘┐Θz,Ww#Θ⁾
```

sub-1000!
Splitting what is a word and what's a character took a while...

Explanation:

```
Ƨ,                 push ", "
   "...‘           push https://gist.github.com/dzaima/3053b8f0222593b8fc4f5cd177ae6dec and replace all `ŗ`s with ", "s
        ┐Θ         split on "|"
          z,W      get inputs index in the lowercase alphabet
             w     gets that item from the array
              #Θ   split on `"` (becuase quote has a single-char push command)
                ⁾  sentence case (uppercases the 1st letters)
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=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,inputs=eg__) or [test all test-cases!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=eiU3QiUyQyUyMSUyMU8lRjhP,inputs=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) (warning: can take a while)

Comment: Nice work getting under 1k. Got a TIO or equivalent where I can test this?

Comment: @Shaggy SOGL is widely known to be under too heavy development so dzaima himself has decided against it iirc.

Comment: @Shaggy ^ yep. But to think of it, actually, it's _possible_ that no more everything breaking updates are coming, so it _might_ be possible sometime in the near future.

Comment: @Shaggy Expect a SOGL online javascript implementation in ~15h (it's midnight now :/). It's mostly done (e.g. this program works), but I'd say that that's the most that works.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 1071 bytes

```
x';!x'%¨AλḞ↕¥βα, »Ṅ'tαt◄l²Za;ṅȦẏ£₇,İ⌊⌋§,ẋZȦṅ´%ḃ⁸ṙż⁸rḃ6ΔbΨËŀ⁶⁶bȦ†;Ḃ⌉säeḃ⁸►,ḃĿ¦İ'mḃβø»)%¥◄£Ẏα¢ȧ×ẏ₅,ŀY4s;Cȧc₇gc₂ȧ≥*εyẏ⁹X∫cẊ←ρ%ż‡ṪeαŸ]1₀fḋ₄k◄ΨdżḊİ'ÿ#G;żδτÖ$,Ḋo¬ḟ×DΦε÷~←ẇ%Eȧ:ØoŸḊ*ωwȧ‼Äd√ṘżẎ₃;£Γφ£⁹&,⁷ŻË□=Ṫ%Γ2u,⌈Λ,£Γü,ẋ=Λ;Flÿ»Jθ Ḟ₂<f¦τḞŻ€εψ=Ȧ%GïΓ≥*Ġτ,⌊⁶lσ₀sżȯ γĿ‰;GẎτ'Ŀ? ¹¬ï gÄmẆwËgø₅t%Hit¦mıḣ,Ż¦Γ□±h,Ïσ»Ψ;Hey«₈öÿ#İ,ä> 'em«‼jαtÿrȮ³₆γ%żẊo¹do∟z,İ¹Ẋz…;Inα'ŸȦṪ,İ'∟l²Ë↕α'≥×8ṡṫ%ȷ;Jd₀¬mΨj≥₄←↕JhĖiŀ?üȷ<θ↕'ȷȷ5;ȷΨJ,¹t's⌋≈ṁm, ẇJγyȷ⌋l%◄/↓İ'mŻ?¹◄lȷk∫θ ΞkΦ;Ka►†ẏ<kγPβ>∫↕γy□<D%←Ṫṁm∟ıα«g←‡,γ₇Ψï◄⌊J$¹sλ≥e;LȦm¦oμW⌋'←ø†oγy£?√%MΨΔ`mφkŀ₂↑ṁØs,□ṡ▲;λ%√ÄdṁØ,Ṁẏ□KΦωζİ've⁶2₃%ȷNgasη@p⌋Ẇηİ'mẏ[ ,£γa;γŻK, ṅṘ←<,ṁ^□ȯ,ṄOṅ◄%ẎO,₀pΠΦ,Öf⁰t⁷ṗΦ;üt₀fŻḣg,øo₀fṁ%,ωχẎ₈Ġ£ρŀs%⁶ḟ3₉□m,λḟ>Ẏπ±⁷¬;Püψ⁷~ÿ/†ẇṖ,Γ%Ṗ¹¬mΨpṘβ%₂Q₈",□□‰Π<□□"¹t'sμQψ⌋n;⌊Q→Ėsα↕'t≥*α□ṙ_₀fωζẇe≥*, uh%γ⌊lrȧwrȧφ,Ÿṙİüp⁷¿δ;⌋□1ε□↔₁ḋ₂¥ωτ%üṗṠ₂ŀ‡{⁵θ∂ä#żġḢ;ẋ≥lṗ€⌈β⁵ȧφȦ…äeḞJs%Tλ$₂nïż◄/…,θσ□ö↔;ȧΣȦ…,ŀ½¦Ės,ġṪαŸ≥ üp%λ"⁵,ÿÜÜ,żμX;ÿ₈U⌋₇/, Ë►ω²¥Ξ%⁸βV√[⁷Övȷ⌈⁰ẏ←d;£×V√↕₆₅Ȧ…äeż▼ ,ṁ^¦m□▼´%Ẇ¿İ'm◄lẆ⌉,ωζαẇ≈eÖrżΔ#⌋≈;ẇψ▼üpẇ., wẊ)ρ ΦγyȮk⌋⌈≤%⌋XΞ, mΨX-żσ↕«½*Ξτa←⁴;X-hġ`λƒζȦ xy⌊₂₉£Yø%«ωŀ-₆k,γ⌋ẏ«Ḣu, γμȯε'ÿ?ws;ŸΨY'sĿwnŸψ⌐Ȧ¦,İ¥;ω%Zig-ZagŀΓḂs, zo₂σ†oεŻΩh;żZr↕,ΩΩŻ⁰↔s,√oż◄↑Ξ¿ψZEA-LOTS!¨-96ṁ½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVX9b9NWFP1XzIcXDb0OjW1omwvdNBhb2QZobCtF@yhraaENRU1ZKZOQbUKatBWwlbmwTaVZqBtoRZOUNnZiFOk9e/JP13@D3z/SnRc0KR8vfi/3nnvuueeN3ciN7@3dzBj7bmZ0Xv2Y2qm3Igt/8DVqUJ1pvJ36@cw01aflcn6CNwaHjNS/G7tp6z6vSHuOhTW5OC8XF/g6S1sLg9jx7/KXeurdkZaX@o@jAN9T@HmUHl6iqliITGnt4nUpdqW5aqSeLRdLOfF05PVfpNNiWIUd7oa1TBZLagiPt9/U@Rog8Eraukd1/k@8LpYBQtp3WWReeDdnfBKv/wxAo/iw43VZWjtEO7PqhOUPyOLGz2lrXhYeJJYORGY59Z@PUD3yvn9b2ubl1FuQdn4c8ak6HAWpN4/conPglBEF9DLJC@cgQM1P8s3UeyKWT5BLO6J5G/HS1px@Ml7/UDyajDwcOZSUZpDdDER@WBb/TP1HCNe6J@07Bq/QUlIAa5b/BpNWM2qLBemUjwGKTktHbjC5WKS/mDomAkXmMfrL@HRCdHi7nzxN9cW2ey9zN8ljHbWlvUk7SfFY7OqnxBYtqZLD1STPVEOs3YnkDkrLRUG8pdF22JFmzTgFKEk@E3b6NO7zTbGljYp8Nm0VZsTCqPBA5rT@2ZVp7mbDeupVWNTmLgI7ZV4fY@J@coe3qWp8NjLLN6RdFLugKKwx8fS4lhnJ4pkZXIVSRGcqfsG3pV2gbV2VD@L84UlZfHILcuE@HtySpmt8fo3qmchTknmOjQwOQGEgpfAHNlCOWH4/9dGqDT1uGv3DKIdvZql6FVtoF9jHyf6x0LkSmX0iiJu95OFJJm7GzfeMuEnVfsb96UwO8pSlYupbWaahYf20PRs38XBCR8cPy8KSUlrU7uO@EnncHIdewDitjJNrnB6CJKFUSKl3nLbPUuM4thXG7Vkw03tCVzLwn6vwqCCsQ50bowqcWWYEFuag@i0ERlv6D3I/R23gHzG@iN0sdycp@A5IMjgP/s3VSUTllT5IR/@SqvTwp2xSGMfI2LYs/IYU4lGOIStokU7DoLaOk5Bad4elvqkE75RPk5uUaBdl/TICKRyB/EDhV6NDOWp@dB350HJqduerdf@ipjS3PWTQdtQ@DYb8u5AtAPUioPUDwsVbWOXPYANl6NDQGYZeXKdVcplwLkurNg09p/4y6BLBtJqoCD5SGWXCm@zOl2/pLCklc91RKIarvJJYkZnTAQ4T9Y60S0iTZcp9nhxXIjV5HSH5pnFWBEkRy9uic7jbhbnUdxgt6fhSGoYergMuNXRwdA7B9yt@1Mus0Wrv6/X@rgwoOIdQiwvXDLTinCz8Hjo5qivFTHftot4l9vGPCrGiD7lG1AbTbozp6OTi/MRUvD6Dd1JgkTK3sCaC6wpnh14aSmVO@W3aUTkLD6VtdW3F5muoPK@LAASl/iqeoJ9m@Vdp7UCvRVs8PRAFYTn1/jEw9Eg4gYMYbmUHDRxS6ZRXul2PXOnP6eepfRBhrokteJlSsOky8jDvTlnsIrURr1Ol@xd4I38FJ3VyLFSepywPGTTA1qm9H9GZ6Ii/xd8MRhcMGKIDBr9Rldhzh5mmDKqVlHgD18EKmuVR41sI7iJKFs4vaobQmprSXOHBMAxOLKttMIrZh5n8jxoonUDrqgnW0m1JoO6IVoF3lAjV1OEH7gGmeKc6mMfAjghnCrAeHng9v2BnDv1zAoDH8i2mzcBJ3kwsDXaMiX4xrs4BUempjtUArTAN6hjoiQJQgyttg786RCtJfkgNp/XSGOgZC8s/Ufvf32k3drWbs8o4MWh2iVcuCE/nG0kpMntQy7gaZDU19/kG@nSDwVEJxko7uCX6ZnJG5FH1QiYXdmauRZ4S2YPY5a5yuzUjKemDV0Z7BodGI5OWcN/lmHYLY2EDlRr4nahNz8Zw0wxOASWjZ/QM5m7V0EjMevHPyW6TMf60wjtJcfDkxz1fnDn/9T5e7fngKDjlr/b29i79Bw)

Another lazy answer using built in compression.